# adding virtual interface to wlan0 with iw : "Device or resource busy (-16)"

Tags: wireless-networking, arch-linux, raspberry-pi, network-interface

## What I'm trying to achieve:

I'm trying to use my *Raspberry Pi 3* as a wifi hotspot.

I'd like to use only wifi to achieve this (I could need it in places where I wouldn't have internet access with ethernet).

So I was following these steps from the archlinux wiki to have both [wifi client and wifi access point with a single wifi device](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_access_point#Wireless_client_and_software_AP_with_a_single_Wi-Fi_device).

## My current situation :

I checked with `iw list` :

```
Wiphy phy0
...
     Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
...
     valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
           total <= 3, #channels <= 2
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
           total <= 4, #channels <=
...
```

My wifi device (the Rpi3 wifi chipset) seems able to handle the Wifi as access point (I managed to make it behave as one and opened a ssh session with it using **hostapd** and **dhcpd**).

If I understand this output well, it also supports both AP and client mode.

## My Rpi state when the problem occures :

I disabled the `hostapd` and `dhcpd4.service` with `systemctl`, and I shut `wlan0` down using `ip link set dev wlan0 down`.

## The actual problem :

Then I tried to add the two `virtual interfaces` (**as root**) I got this :

```
# iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan0_sta type managed addr 12:34:56:78:ab:cd 
command failed: Device or resource busy (-16)     
# iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan0_ap  type managed addr 12:34:56:78:ab:ce
command failed: Device or resource busy (-16)
```

Same result when trying with `phy` names or with `wlan0` up.

What could I try to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it looks like I misunderstood the `iw list` output.

If the RPI3 chipset was able to behave like this, the two mode it could use simultaneously would be between the same `#{...}` in the `iw list` output.

The person helping me on IRC with this also suggested me to use a Wifi dongle to solve this problem.